# How to remove Android OAuth2 permission I granted myself

Tags: android, oauth, google-play-services

Today I managed to make the Google Play Services Sample OAuth Android program work.

I granted myself Scope to 'View basic information about your account' and retrieve my name.

Question is, how do I remove this now that it has been granted.  I know I can invalidate the token through code but was wondering how do it within my google account.

From https://www.google.com/settings/security
Then taking 'View Account Permissions'
I expected to see and entry for MyOauthTwo but unfortunately not.

Am I looking in the correct place?  If not then where should I be looking.

I have two accounts on my phone one I gave access to and one I cancelled out of.  The one still has access currently so I expected it to be present.

Any help as usual would be appreciated.

Regards,

Jim

Comment: Might it be that a valid access token stays valid until it expires and revoke access means only that the application is not allowed to get a new access token without first needing to get permission?

Answer (score 1):

Try going to https://cloud.google.com/console/project, APIs & auth, Consent Screen, and change the Product Name to something recognizable.

The default name is easily missed if you have a large list of account permissions.

Comment: Thanks Patrick I tried above, but my project is not listed.  I have 4 GAE applications and one API application which I set up a long time ago for Google Drive testing.  All I am trying to do is an Android sample program with no special/other api, so I don't need a key or secret.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking in the right place.  I had a similar problem and found I had to log in to   https://www.google.com/settings/security from each account separately.

Comment: Thanks Heureux but it's not there.  Could it be named something different?  Could it be that only 'signed' play store applications create entries there?

Comment: I don't think so, even my pre-deployment projects showed up in permissions. It could be named differently, check the 'app name' defined in your manifest.  Do you have a permission listed that is only 'View basic information about your account'?

Comment: Thanks Heureux but still not working.  I checked the app name in the manifest and it was as I expected MyOauthTwo.  When I tried the app again just now, the token I had from last week must have expired, so I logged in again.  Still not displayed in settings/security.